# What is the maximum number of users/size a Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 can support?

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

What is the maximum number of users and data size a windows sharepoint services 3.0 can support? I'm planning to deploy a WSS 3.0 on a 100gig harddisk with 2 gig RAM for 100 users.

Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Honestly, these days I can't countenance putting together any server that has less than 3 or 4GB of RAM, especially if it's a 64-bit server (in which case 4GB is my minimum).

Comment: You should also ask this question on www.serverfault.com.

Comment: I can increase the system resources that's no big deal. They are all Virtual boxes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Plan for software boundaries (Windows SharePoint Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790(office.12).aspx)

Comment: wow, I was tired googling for this page. Awesome! Thanks.

BTW, how did you find it?

Comment: @Broken Link: I used "wss 3 limits" (I have seen this before and knew it was in a large list-all page).